# The series$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!})^p$ converges if and only if $p>2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, binomial-coefficients

Problem: The series$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!})^p$ converges if and only if $p>2$

My question is: can anyone solve the problem by using binomial coefficients or Stirling's formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that
$$
\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!} = \frac{(2n-1)!! (2n)!! }{(2n)!! (2n)!!} = 
 \frac{(2n)! }{ 2^{2n} (n!)^2 } \sim (\text{ using Stirling's formula}) \\
\frac{\sqrt{2\pi 2n} (2n)^{2n} e^{-2n} }{ 2^{2n} (2\pi n) n^{2n} e^{-2n} }= 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}}.
$$
Hence, you effectively have a series of $(\frac{1}{n^{1/2}})^p$ and need $p/2 >1$ for convergence. You may use comparison tests to make things rigorous (namely, the passage from the original term to reduction by Stirling).